# Why is A(A+B) = A [Absorption Law]?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Could you proof it to me that A(A+B) = A?

AA + BA [AA = A]

A + AB

Then what?

Comment: Use a truth table.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you are looking for a way to prove the identity using a calculus. So far you have used distributivity an idempotency.

Recall that `A = A1` so you get `A1+AB` and you can use distributivity again, this time in the other direction. Then two obvious steps.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof:
$$
A \stackrel{(1)}= A \cdot 1
\stackrel{(2)}= A \cdot (1+B)
\stackrel{(3)}= A \cdot 1 + A \cdot B
\stackrel{(4)}= A + A \cdot B
\stackrel{(5)}= A \cdot A + A \cdot B
\stackrel{(6)}= A \cdot (A+B).
$$

Axioms used:

(1),(4) multiplicative identity

(2) absorption

(3),(6) distributivity

(5) idempotence

Answer (score 2):

I always liked the $\min, \max$ definitions of $\cdot$ and $+$, since some courses in boolean algebra just give those laws and ask you to accept them. [[Boolean Algebra: Basic Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations)]

\begin{align*}
x \land y &= x \cdot y = \min(x,y)\\
x \lor y &= x + y = \max(x,y)
\end{align*}
where $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$.

So $A(A+B)$ becomes:
$$ \min(A, \max(A,B)) $$

- **Case 1:** If $A \leq B$ then

\begin{align*}
\min(A, \color{red}{\max(A,B)}) &= \min(A, \color{red}{B})\\
 &= \min(A, B) = A\\
\end{align*}

- **Case 2:** If $A \geq B$ follows the same way as the first one.

Answer (score -1):

- A(A+B)         as The AND operation distributes
- over the OR operation
- for all x, y, z ∈ B
- x • (y + z) = (x • y) + (x • z) so
- A(A+B) = AA+AB      Idempotent x • x = x
- = A+AB
- = A(1+B)      as 1+B=1 so
- = A(1)            as A.1=A so
- = A

Comment: I don't see any significant difference between this answer and Raiyan's existing answer.

Comment: the question was "Could you proof it to me that A(A+B) = A?"
not  "Could you proof it to me that A=A(A+B) ?"
is it right?